# API Data Reading

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I am fairly new to API and it's working. Currently we are developing an web application for the patients to monitor there Blood Pressure(BP) and the reports will automatically be available in our web application.

We have agreement with one company who is providing us with the BP devices. Device will send send response to our Callback URL as soon as patient takes the test.
The document which they are providing is bit confusing to me as I am very new in API's.

I am able to generate Token using my API key and passphrase

```
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => 'https://xxx/auth/generateToken',
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
 "api-key" : "myapikey",
 "pass-phrase" : "passphrase"
 }',
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/json'
 ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

But now after generating the token what I need to do? are they going to send report response in json format right after generating token. or do I need to send any Get response to get the response?
Really confused here.

DOCUMENTATION

The api token can be generated/refreshed by the following API call :
http url -- https://xxx/auth/generateToken
http method -- POST
http headers -- Content-Type:application/json
body :

```
 {
  "api-key" : "your api key sent to you",
  "pass-phrase" : "passphrase sent to you"
  }
  response :
  {
  "token" : "your api token"
  }
```

The token generated by this API call will be sent with the Reading
payload in the http header param name(X-CARE-API-TOKEN).
You can use this token to validate the source authenticity.

The following is the json payload that will be pushed for each reading
taken by the device to your api url.
method : POST
the HTTP Headers will be :

1. X-CARE-API-KEY = {your api key}
2. X-CARE-API-TOKEN = {your api token}
   the HTTP Body will be :

---

---

### For Blood Pressure Monitor Device

---

```
 {
  "readingData": {
  "id": 572043,
  "device": {
  "name": "Blood Pressure Monitor",
  "serialNumber": "BP800TEST04",
  "manufacturerNumber": "301",
  "model": "800"
  },
  "transmissionTime": 1612940047,
  "readingTime": 1612940041,
  "source": "Device",
  "userNumber": 1,
  "readings": [
  {
  "id": 1,
  "type": "BP Systolic",
  "value": "109",
  "unit": "mm/hg"
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "type": "BP Diastolic",
  "value": "145",
  "unit": "mm/hg"
  },
  {
  "id": 3,
  "type": "BP Heartrate",
  "value": "157",
  "unit": "Beats Per Minute"
  },
  {
  "id": 4,
  "type": "Irregular Heartbeat",
  "value": "1"
  },
  {
  "id": 5,
  "type": "Battery Level",
  "value": "98",
  "unit": "Percent"
  },
  {
  "id": 6,
  "type": "Signal Strength",
  "value": "10",
  "unit": "db"
  }
  ]
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After token generation, there is usually another API Call to actually get data against the token generated.

It should be another URL with method at the end.
Hence there will be another CURL Call.

There may be some documentation for this from your API Developers.
Or you might have to get their support.

Comment: Thankyou Shoaib to clarifying me this. they have not provided any other URL call to get the response. I may need to ask there support team.

Comment: Support keep on mentioning response will be send to our CallBack URL every time patient takes a test. Now if they themselves sending response only thing lift for me to use json_decode the response and save it in our database. am I right? but then what is the use to generate token in our callback URL?

Comment: Yes you are right, the response needs to go in Database. The Call Back URL would be from your server where you will be processing the data they send when a patient takes test.

The token however may be generated once in a day, or week or month or even more than that. 
This token will just provide authenticity for your server. I assume they might require the token in headers or URL as a pram